# JDBC file in Hibernate configuration not found

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

When I want to add an database connection in Hibernate there are no drivers. 
I selected Database connection -> "New" then "Generic JDBC" and then there are no drivers listed:

[image: no drivers found]
[image: hibernate.cfg.xml]
Does anybody know how to add there a driver for PostgreSQL?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use hibernate_cfg.xml and configure all the information in xml file. Usually the  driver configuration goes in dialect properity

Comment: Ok, how can I generate the Java mapping files from the db schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Postgresql JDBC Driver from [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/). Then clic the button on the right of Driver combo in "New connection profile" and choose the Postgresql JDBC driver you have downloaded. See [Creating a Driver Definition](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700344899.html) at Eclipse help webpage.

Answer (score 1):

[Refer this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/) tutorial . I think you want to create pojo class from the db tables..You can use Hibernate or [JPA entities](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user/tasks021.htm) .

Comment: We used the tutorial of your first link, but we can't select an db driver, see above.